# append data from list in new list that doesn't occur in other list

Tags: python, list

so what I have is two lists, list1 (axisCoordinatesConnectedLines)has all my data and the other one(blockLineCoordinates) has the data that needs to be removed from axisCoordinatesConnectedLines. while trying to delete or remove the data from blockLineCoordinates in axisCoordinatesConnectedLines, an index error occurd after deleting 1 item. which makes sense because the index of the list changes after deleting something.

I tried appending the data from axisCoordinatesConnectedLines which does not occur in blockLineCoordinates to a new list to avoid the indexing error. this works and it detects if the two lists have any similarities but the only thing that I need to fix now is that if I run the code below I get the new list four times and every time the unwanted data is removed but put back in next list.

to make it a bit more clear if blocklinecoordinates has the index of 0,1,2,3 and that's how it is iterating than my result is:

[data and 1,2,3,4 are in list]

[data and *0* , 2, 3, 4 are in list]

[data and *0,1*, 3,4 are in list] etc

instead of giving me the original list once (axisCoordinatesConnectedLines) with a new name,listzonderbl and without the data from Blocklinecoordinates in it.

if anyone knows how to solve this I would really appreciate your help!!

```
axisCoordinatesConnectedLines2=[[[(2,1),(2,2)]],[[(6,0),(6, 1)],[(6, 1), (7, 1)]],          [[(4, 1), (4, 2)],[(4, 1), (5, 1)], [(4, 2), (4, 3)],[(4, 3), (5, 3)]]]        


#list which coordinates need to beremoved
blockLineCoordinates2 = [[(4, 1), (4, 2)], [(4, 2), (4, 3)], [(6, 0), (6, 1)], [(6, 1), (7, 1)]]  


listzonderbl = []    
for k in range(len(blockLineCoordinates)):
    for n in range(len(axisCoordinatesConnectedLines)):
        newlist = []
        for i in range(len(axisCoordinatesConnectedLines[n])):
            while len(axisCoordinatesConnectedLines):
                if blockLineCoordinates[k]!= axisCoordinatesConnectedLines[n][i]:
                    newlist.append(axisCoordinatesConnectedLines[n][i])
                else:
                    print('bl detected', axisCoordinatesConnectedLines[n][i])
                    break
        listzonderbl.append(newlist)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that? Your exmaple is not really clear. A minimal example should remove any unnecessary information.

```
L1 = [[[(2,1),(2,2)]],[[(6,0),(6, 1)],[(6, 1), (7, 1)]], [[(4, 1), (4, 2)],[(4, 1), (5, 1)], [(4, 2), (4, 3)],[(4, 3), (5, 3)]]]
L2 = [[(4, 1), (4, 2)], [(4, 2), (4, 3)], [(6, 0), (6, 1)], [(6, 1), (7, 1)]] 

L1_new = list()

for sublist in L1:
    L1_new.append([])
    
    for coord in sublist:
        if coord not in L2:
            L1_new[-1].append(coord)
```

Output:

```
[[[(2, 1), (2, 2)]], [], [[(4, 1), (5, 1)], [(4, 3), (5, 3)]]]
```

Comment: why do you not use range(Len()) ?

Comment: @Sorsha Why would you? It's a very bad habit to iterate a list with range. A list is an iterable, meaning you can directly get one element after the next from the list with `for elt in L`. If you need the indices, there is a great chance you also need the element at the corresponding indices. In this last case, `for i in range(len(L))` is still not the correct solution. The correct one is `for i, elt in enumerate(L)`.

Comment: thankyou ! I'm still quite new to all of this so this helpen a lot !

Comment: @Sorsha You are welcome. Try the different pieces of code on your own and you will get what they do. If the answer was helpful, please consider upvoting and accepting the answer.